# How do I convert a user input from a web page and convert it to markdown language dynamically so that it can be converted to PDF using jsPdf

Tags: html, markdown, jspdf

I am trying to create a web application/site which would be more of a resume building website,
My query is:
I would be taking input from users in a form, and show them the output as various document format like PDF, .doc etc.
What I want is that once the user clicks on submit button, the html input should be rendered and converted to markdown and using jspdf it should be converted to PDF,
or else directly convert the html directly to custom pdf template, I mean to say populate the pdf based on the input from html input
Any opensource solution

Answer (score 0):

This is my go to open source project for converting html to markdown: https://github.com/domchristie/to-markdown

I also wrote my own html form helper to convert html to markdown and vice-versa, but it does it in real time so it might be overkill for this project: https://github.com/justinmc/markdown-html-form